# Letters are inputted uppercase after system boot

Tags: 17.10, plasma

When trying to input something e.g. in Konsole (KDE session) letters are inputted uppercase after system boot.

I don't have Caps Lock key enabled so can't simply press it to disable uppercase.

Does not happen all the time but rarely.

Caps Lock is off:

```
$ xset -q | grep ' Caps Lock:'
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock:
```

But when I trigger this command the issue gets fixed:

```
/usr/bin/xdotool key Caps_Lock
```

What the problem could be, how to fix properly and/or how to identify the situation that Caps Lock is pressed (for e.g. a quick fix via cron) even though the `xset` tool says it's not?